# Error when cloning svg in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I am trying to clone several svgs from the same data, but when I apply a colour to one of them it also applies to the others as well. I'm not sure I am cloning the svg correctly. Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var svgObject = null;

fabric.loadSVGFromURL("http://fabricjs.com/assets/131.svg", function(objects, options) {

  svgObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);       

  var object1 = fabric.util.object.clone(svgObject);

  colourSVG(object1, "rgb(0,0,0)", "rgba(151,0,0,1)");

  canvas.add(object1);

  var object2 = fabric.util.object.clone(svgObject);
  object2.top = 200;
  canvas.add(object2).renderAll();

});

function colourSVG(_obj, _keyColourString, _fillColourString){

  if (!_obj.paths) {
    _obj.setFill(_fillColourString);
  }
  else if (_obj.paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _obj.paths.length; i++) {

      if(_obj.paths[i].fill === _keyColourString){ 
        _obj.paths[i].setFill(_fillColourString);

        console.log("colour found");        
      }      
      else{

        console.log(_obj.paths[i].fill);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to pass it through the `colourSVG` function after cloning it? Maybe I'm confused as to when/how you are setting the color after this initial example code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were just cloning the objects incorrectly.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var svgObject = null;

fabric.loadSVGFromURL("http://fabricjs.com/assets/131.svg", function(objects, options) {

  svgObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  
  svgObject.clone(function(o) {
    colourSVG(o, "rgb(0,0,0)", "rgba(151,0,0,1)");
    canvas.add(o);
  });
  svgObject.clone(function(o) {
    o.top = 200;
    canvas.add(o);
  });
  canvas.renderAll();

});

function colourSVG(_obj, _keyColourString, _fillColourString) {

  if (!_obj.paths) {
    _obj.setFill(_fillColourString);
  } else if (_obj.paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _obj.paths.length; i++) {

      if (_obj.paths[i].fill === _keyColourString) {
        _obj.paths[i].setFill(_fillColourString);

        console.log("colour found");
      } else {

        console.log(_obj);
        console.log(_obj.paths[i].fill);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```